# How to detect a running process in WiX?

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm using WiX 3 to build a setup file. I would like to know whether Outlook is running during the installation. If Outlook is still running, the setup should notify the users to close it or have to reboot after the installation.

I noticed that there is a feature util:CloseApplication can send a message to close Outlook directly, but that's not very friendly. I would like to know whether the FileInUse dialog can be called in such situation?

Comment: Sounds similar to this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710647/prompt-user-to-close-application-during-uninstall-in-wix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710647/prompt-user-to-close-application-during-uninstall-in-wix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prompt user to close application during uninstall (in WiX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710647/prompt-user-to-close-application-during-uninstall-in-wix)