# Don't install if a program is running

Tags: wix

I have a wix installer.  How can I prevent the install if a program is running?  I don't want to have the installer close the program.  It may not be in a state where it is safe to close.  I want to tell the user they need to close the application and either wait for the user to close it, or just exit the install.

Comment: This seems to be the like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335260/how-to-detect-the-running-process-in-wix3
which references this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710647/prompt-user-to-close-application-during-uninstall-in-wix

Comment: Windows Installer has features to handle "files in use". It's not the same as "a program is running" but is that what you need?

Comment: "Files is use" sort of works, but allows the user to ignore the issue and continue on.

Comment: I did have <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" /> in my dialog.  I removed that so at least the installer is no longer offering to close the applications

Answer (score 0):

I removed `<DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />` and that appears to prevent the installer from prompting to close the application.

However, the default FileInUse dialog allows you to ignore the fact that files are in use.  I tried to find a way to remove the ignore option but was unable to.  The best option I could come up with was to remap the "Ignore" button to "Exit".

```
<Publish Dialog="FilesInUse" Control="Ignore" Event="EndDialog" Value="Exit">1</Publish>
```

I first tried to map "Ignore" to "Retry".  That worked the first time the FilesInUse dialog appeared, but not after your retried once.

This is definitely a hack, but its the best option I've found so far.