# How to prompt user for active processes and terminate them during uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

I am using Wix 3.5 with such codes:

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseMyApp" CloseMessage="yes" Target="Foo.exe" RebootPrompt="no"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='WixCloseApplications' Before='InstallValidate' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It does really terminate the applications forcefully and silently before uninstall actually happens.
However, I want to know if it is possible to prompt users before such termination happens with a message box, and proceed termination if allowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing some references

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710647/prompt-user-to-close-application-during-uninstall-in-wix)